# How to test if \ symbol (backslash) is in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to run this command `if r"\" in text:` and it doesn't work. It thinks the whole line is a string. How do I fix this?

Comment: `if r"\\" in text`

Comment: Special characters need escaping.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, make sure you show which kind of error you get, and that you provide the minimum code to reproduce the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raw literals aren't *completely* raw.  The relevant paragraph of documentation is at the very bottom of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals, just before the next section ("String literal concatenation") begins:

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, *a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash* (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal, not as a line continuation.

(Emphasis in original.)

So, you can write `r"\\"` and get a string containing *two* backslashes, and you can write `r"\""` and get a string containing one backslash and one double-quote character, but if you want a string containing *just one backslash*, you can't do it with a raw literal.  You need to write `"\\"` instead.

Comment: `'\\' in 'ABC\nDEF'` returns `False` under Python 3.9. What am I missing?

Comment: `'\\'` evaluates to a containing one backslash. `'ABC\nDEF'` evaluates to a string containing *no* backslashes.  What did you expect to happen?  (Maybe you should ask a new question, I'm not seeing how this is connected to the behavior of raw literals?)

Comment: I now understand. `'\\' in r'ABC\nDEF'` returns True. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are struggling with the escaping characters.

Because `\` is an escaping character you have to escape it to mean "*this character*" and not "*what following will be escaped*".

```
if '\\' in 'foo\\':
```

Comment: What is the string is `\\foo`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
"\\"
```

That is, an escaped backslash, rather than an escaped quote.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "\\" in text
```

This should work, you just need to escape it